# Grayscale SVG not working on firefox

Tags: css, svg

[link](http://demos.namanyayg.com/furiousnerds)

In chrome, it is working perfect. However, in Firefox, the images do not appear.

I have set the SVG's mime type, and mime type checkers are displaying that the mime type is correct.

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using the new [shorthand notation](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html#FilterFunction) for filter effects on html elements (as defined [here](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html)), in Firefox you'll have to use the url(#...) notation for filters (also part of the same spec, and of SVG 1.1 where it's been working for a long time).

If you want to see how to do a grayscale filter that works in most browsers [see here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/grayscale-filter.svg), and if you want to read about how you make it apply to some html see e.g [here](http://robert.ocallahan.org/2008/06/applying-svg-effects-to-html-content_04.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I removed the SVG. Previously, I had used the exact same method as described in the last link, but it didn't work on FF, so I ditched it.